# let's Encrypt Bitnami SSL tool Error: [account] is not registered. Use 'run' to register a new account

Tags: lets-encrypt, bitnami

I am trying to run the bitnami let's encrypt SSL tool to setup an SSL certificate on my amazon lightsail wordpress server.

this is the tool:

`sudo /opt/bitnami/bncert-tool`

read more about it here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/linux-lightsail-ssl-bitnami/

but when i run it, I get this error:

`Account [email address of account] is not registered. Use 'run' to register a new account.`

it's not clear how to resolve this from the let's encrypt or bitnami documentation.  How do I get around this ?

Comment: Did you previously generate a certificate using the Bitnami HTTPS configuration tool and a different email account? You can take a look at the letsencrypt files to see if you are using the same email or not `sudo ls -la /opt/bitnami/letsencrypt/accounts`. You can try to [manually revoke the certificate](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/understand-bncert/#manually-revoking-an-existing-certificate) and then run the Bitnami HTTPS configuration tool again.

Comment: Files /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/bitnami-ssl.conf and the /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/APPNAME-https-vhost.conf files (where APPNAME depends on the application in use) did not exist. I created the former and added dummy certificates. Afterwards, when running the revoke command I got "Certificate is expired error". The original error described by psvj in his question persists. Any suggestions? (Amazon Lightsail, Apache).

Interestingly bitnami shows a "Warning: A certificate for the list of domains you entered already exists. It will be used instead of generating a new one."

Comment: Well, after trying for the second time (the bitnami tool), it worked. I do not know why or how, but my advice would be: in case of the error described by psvj, try Jota's suggestion of revoking manually, then two times the bitnami command, and maybe it will start working, as in my case. Cheers